# How to find if a Path has been used as source for a symbolic link

Tags: java, java-7

Lets say I have a file located on the filesystem which I know is not a symbolic link, i.e. a regular file or directory.

How can I check that there aren't any symbolic links referencing to this file in Java?

I assume I maybe have to use `Paths.walkFileTree` with `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS` but I am not sure, maybe there is an easier way.

Worth noting is that I also know in which directory there may contain symbolic links pointing to this particular file/directory. The symbolic links will not have the same name as the actual file/directory.

I don't use Java 8 so any solution compatible with Java 7 would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert on this but I'm pretty sure this depends on the OS you're running on and you might even have to scan all files to discover any symbolic links that point to this file (AFAIK there's no pointer/reference back from the file to the link itself).

Comment: I can't even think of a way of doing this that is efficient. I feel like you will probably have to search the entire disk to find all links. Then you also have to deal with permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of a symbolic link (at least in Linux) has no back-pointer to links that reference it. To find such links you'd have to scan the entire filesystem.